# Best algorithm to group data by similarity (same ID)

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, grouping

here is reference code:

```
struct MyData
{
int ID;

// other members
};

std::vector<MyData> inputData;

std::vector<std::vector<MyData> > outputData = GroupByIDs(inputData);
```

Basically what I want to do is iterate the input data and group the objects by ID into a new mini vector which I would push in the output vector. So in the end I would have a vector of sub-vectors where every sub-vector contains objects with identical `ID`.

Is there a *cookie-cutter most efficient* algorithm designed to do this? Because I can only  think of algorithms with a high complexity.

Comment: What is your concern? How to determine the groups, how to determine similarity? Or how to transfer data efficiently from inputData to outputData?

Comment: Currently I keep a buffer where I keep the already added IDs and I end up doing a LOT of searches every iteration, I need an efficient way to do it

Comment: OK, How is similarity defined? Exploiting properties of your similarity definition has big potential for optimizations.

Comment: @peterchen I edited the question, by similarity I meant same ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by sorting your elements according to `ID` and then use [std::upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) to find the end position of each group:

For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct MyData
{
    int id;
    std::string info;

    MyData(int id, const std::string& info): id(id), info(info) {}

    // for sorting by id
    bool operator<(const MyData& d) const { return id < d.id; }
};

// function requires sorted data as input
std::vector<std::vector<MyData> > GroupByIDs(const std::vector<MyData>& data)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<MyData> > groups;

    decltype(data.end()) upper;

    for(auto lower = data.begin(); lower != data.end(); lower = upper)
    {
        // get the upper position of all elements with the same ID
        upper = std::upper_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), *lower);

        // add those elements as a group to the output vector
        groups.emplace_back(lower, upper);
    }

    return groups;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<MyData> data {{2, "A"}, {4, "B"}, {3, "C"}, {4, "D"}, {9, "E"}, {3, "F"}};

    // function requires sorted data
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
    std::vector<std::vector<MyData> > groups = GroupByIDs(data);

    for(auto const& group: groups)
    {
        if(!group.empty())
            std::cout << "group: " << group.front().id << '\n';

        for(auto const& d: group)
            std::cout << "     : " << d.info << '\n';

        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
group: 2
     : A

group: 3
     : C
     : F

group: 4
     : B
     : D

group: 9
     : E
```

Answer (score 1):

You're a little vague but I imagine you could use `std::sort` or friends (`std::stable_sort`, `std::partition`, `std::stable_partition`). Then you use `std::copy` from one vector's iterators to another vector.

Comment: Yeah, that might work, just sort them and them copy each "same ID" segment to a new vector.

Answer (score 1):

> I edited the question, by similarity I meant same ID

Implementation:

```
auto MapByIDs(std::vector<MyData> inputData)
{
    std::map<std::vector<MyData>> result;
    for(auto &x: inputData)
        result[x.ID].emplace_back(std::move(x));
    return result;
}

auto GroupByIDs(std::vector<MyData> inputData)
{
    auto map = MapByIDs(std::move(inputData));
    std::vector<std::vector<MyData>> result;
    for(auto &x: map)
        result.emplace_back(std::move(x.second));
    return result;
}

auto outputData = GroupByIDs(std::move(inputData));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used a hash table, you could do something like:

```
Create a hash table that maps from ID to vector<MyData>
Iterate through the input data:
    If the hash table doesn't contain a vector for that ID:
        Create a vector<MyData> and add it to the hash table
    Push the input item into that vector<MyData>
Iterate through the entry set for the hash table:
    Put the vector<MyData> into the vector<vector<MyData>>
Return the vector<vector<MyData>>
```

This should be something like `O(n)` average case.  Worst case would be something like `O(n^2)`, I would think, if the hash function is bad.

Comment: Note that point3&4 is done automatically with `std::unordered_map<int, std:::vector<MyData>>::operator[]` :-) so only `map[data.ID].push_back(data)` is required.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm not a C++ programmer.  Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold a **map** of IDs, which map between ID and vector containing items with the ID. Then iterate over input, for each element check the map for it's ID, and if it's a new one create a new vector. Your complexity would be O(NlogM), where N is input size and M number of possible IDs.

Pseudocode:

```
    for(Item in inputData)
            if(Item.ID in IDMap)
                    IDVec = IDMap[Item.ID]
                    IDVec.push(Item)
            else
                    IDVec = new Vector
                    IDMap.push(IDVec, Item.ID)
                    OutputVec.push(IDVec)
```

Comment: `if(Item.ID in IDMap)` is not required with map: `IDMap[Item.ID].push_back(Item);` is enough.

Comment: That's true, I just wrote it more simply so that the complexity is clear

Answer (score 0):

*Option 1:*
Sort input by ID, then iterate over the sorted input, accumulating and coyping sequences of data with the same ID and copying them to the target using vector's `vector(iter, iter)` CTor.

sort requires a comparator:

```
bool less_than_by_ID(MyData const & a, MyData const & b) 
{ return a.ID < b.ID; }
```

*Option 2:*
Keep the items in a multiset or multimap keyed by ID, use `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` of the respective container to get the ranges of the individual keys.  (Algorithmically, it's the same)

*Option 3:*
change your output data structure to

```
std::map<int, std::vector<MyData> > outputData;
```

and just throw the data at the container:

```
for(auto data : inputData)
  outuptData[data.ID].push_back(data);
```